# How to change the next cycle billing date in Authorize.Net recurring payment

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I have used https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML/ library for implement recurring payment for my website.

Is there an option to change the next cycle billing date? For example, initially I have subscribed for one plan on  04-03-2018 for every month. But I need to change Next cycle subscription to start on 06-04-2018 . Is it possible in authorize.net recurring payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the date of a recurring billing subscription. If you need to change the date you need to cancel the current subscription and create a new one with a starting date of 06-04-2018. If the billing dates are going to not be consistent then you would want to switch from using the ARB API to the CIM API which allows you to create payment accounts and charge against them at a future date. Then you can build your own billing engine to charge users when necessary.